# angular bindings not getting applied

Tags: angular, webpack

I have an MVC project with Angular JS running. I have multiple angular SPAs in my application. I upgraded one of the SPA's completely to Angular with 4.3.5 version without having any dependencies on any of the SPA's.

Angular code compiles fine and no console errors. When I launch the application it routes to the default route configured with angular and takes me to the correct page. However the angular bindings dont get applied to my html. I see the following in my dev tools.

```
<div class="login-container col-md-12">
    <div class="logos">
        <img class="login-product-logo">
    </div>
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->

    <input name="test">

    <form novalidate="">
        <div class="controls">
            <!---->

            <!---->
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Above input control has ngModel bindings. There are multiple div's with ngIf directives which show up as commented html tags in the above html.

I have ported the SPA with same exact code in an angular-cli project and everything seems to be working fine.

I have ported the same packages with the same exact versions and webpack configuration same as the cli project but I keep on getting to the same end result. HTML for the angular cli project is below.

```
<div class="login-container col-md-12">
    <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"}-->
    <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"}-->
    <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"}-->

    <p>Test</p> 


    <input ng-reflect-model="Test" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">

    <form novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
        <div class="controls">
            <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"}--><div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <input class="btn btn-link NoPadding windows-auth" id="windowsLoginButton" type="submit" value="Log in using Microsoft Windows domain">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"}-->
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm not able to figure out what would be removing my angular bindings from the html.

Has anyone run into this issue?

Comment: The *ngIf directive will remove the element it is on and all of its children if the ngIf condition is true.

Comment: Yes that's the expected behavior of the ngIf. Its not only the divs with ngIF, its the input control as well. Ill edit my question and show you the html of my angular-cli project to make my question more clear.

Answer (score -1):

Today I had the same mistake. The point was that I don't input variable 'text' in HTML

It was:

```
<div class="alert-wrap" *ngIf="text">
<div class="alert"
[ngClass]="{
    'alert-success': type === 'success',
    'alert-warning': type === 'warning',
    'alert-danger': type === 'danger'
}"
>
    
</div>
```

The problem was solved after adding

{{ text }}

```
<div class="alert-wrap" *ngIf="text">
<div class="alert"
[ngClass]="{
    'alert-success': type === 'success',
    'alert-warning': type === 'warning',
    'alert-danger': type === 'danger'
}"
>
    <p>{{ text }}</p>
</div>
```